# An Inquisitive Riley

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, acrostic

I'm taking a quick break from my new story riddle, and I decided to craft another simple Riley for you guys. Good luck to all of you!

> Mix up the prefix, using quail equals bird; but don't move too fast, or you'll scare off the third.
>
> Ask for the infix, from the guy down the street; he's the one standing, no shoes on his feet.
>
> Keep up the good work, the suffix you seek; rationalization your enemy, no wait, that's just me.
>
> Remember this warning, I've told you before; the answers are here, but you're searching for more.

Explain the title.

**Hint**: Since this is another one that seems to be proving difficult, here's a hint:

> The answers are here, hidden from you; within plain sight, within your view.
>  The acrostic is wrong, once again that's a fact; rearrange it to find, the word you want back.

Comment: Twas an extra word that wasn't supposed to make it. LOL

Comment: The second letters spell in all the lines is "I see"

Comment: But do you see? That’s not the true acrostic, but instead a play on words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm... I think I have the answer but I'm really not sure about my explanations.

The answer is

> **Question**

Explanation

Title

> An inquisitive person asks **questions**

Acrostic

> MAKR is an anagram of MARK. A question mark is something used by inquisitive people when writing a question.

Mix up the prefix, using quail equals bird; but don't move too fast, or you'll scare off the third.

> Ok, I think this creates **que** by taking the first two letter of quail and the first letter of equals. I think "scare off the third" means that the e in "que" is separated a bit from the rest of the prefix.

Ask for the infix, from the guy down the street; he's the one standing, no shoes on his feet.

> This line has two words that start with **st** (standing and street) I think there might be more to this hint though...

Keep up the good work, the suffix you seek; rationalization your enemy, no wait, that's just me.

> the word "rationalization" has the letters **tion** twice in it.

Remember this warning, I've told you before; the answers are here, but you're searching for more.

> The letters are all in the puzzle however once you get the answer you're left with a **question** which is searching for more information.

Comment: Very good find! You actually have everything correct!